# Lenovo E330 - Intel N-2230 Bluetooth issue

Tags: bluetooth, lenovo-laptop

My E330 is behaving very oddly.  I had connected a Bluetooth keyboard, using the built in Intel Bluetooth adapter.  I don't use this Bluetooth keyboard every day - just when in certain locations (it's a portable keyboard).

Today The laptop won't connect to the keyboard.  Further, it won't connect to any Bluetooth device.  Further, no other Bluetooth device can see it.  The Bluetooth adapter has disappeared from my network connections list too.  The Device driver is still showing as healthy (it is a single Intel N-2230 board & driver, which supports both Bluetooth and WiFi).  I've un-installed and reinstalled this.

In Devices and hardware, right-clicking on my computer, there are no hardware resources assigned to my Bluetooth (but I don;t know whether there should be here).

I installed Bluetooth command line tools, which reports that no Bluetooth radio could be found.

I've checked the BIOS, and Bluetooth is enabled.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Press Win key + R to open up Run and type msconfig and go to startup tab. See if you have bluetooth adapter enabled there. Also try this: go to services tab on the MSCONFIG window and check on "Hide all Microsoft Services" and make sure bluetooth adapter software is not stopped.

If there is nothing wrong with these, I would recommend restoring the computer back when the bluetooth was working properly.

To do that: go to Start>ALL Programs>Accessories>System Tools> System Restore and click on the date you like to restore your computer to. Would recommend going back about a week.

That should restore all your settings and installed softwares.